# How to check for a winner in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I need to check if spaces on my board are empty. It will return True if there are no more available spaces.

Here is my code:

```
#
# File: done.py
# Purpose: Complete the code in the function "done" below to determine whether a 
# the game is over.
#

def print_board(board):
    print(board[0:3])
    print(board[3:6])
    print(board[6:9])


#
# Function: string_to_list
# Purpose: converts a string to a list of characters.
def string_to_list(board):
    my_list = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        my_list.append(board[i])
    return my_list

#
# Function done
# Input: A list of character (of length 9)
# Output: Return True if there are no remaining spaces
#         Return False if there is an open spot.
def done(board):
    #HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP

board1 = "XXX XXOOO"
lboard1 = string_to_list(board1)
print("First board")
print_board(lboard1)
assert (not done(lboard1)), "The first board has a space, you returned true"
print("Test passed")
board2 = "XXXXXXOOO"
lboard2 = string_to_list(board2)
print("Second Board")
print_board(lboard2)
assert (done(lboard2)), "This second board has no space -- you returned False" 
print("Test passed")
print("If you got this far, you passed the first two tests")
```

I need help with what goes inside of the def done(board):

I tried using if statements that would check for available spaces but I didn't really know how to start.

Comment: `list` itself can convert a string (an iterable of characters) into a list of characters. `list("abc") == ['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Comment: *"#HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP"*: it seems you didn't do any ting yet. I suggest you start working on it, and when you bump into an issue you ask a question focused on that problem.